# How can I tell what the default parameters are for CvSVMParams in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I'm pretty new to opencv and just getting used to C++ programming so this question might be pretty silly. What values are the the parameters in "struct CvSVMParams" initialized with if I leave them as their defaults and train a classifier without modifying them?

Answer (score 1):

well, since opencv is open source you could just look at the source code

but it's often faster to just google it, like https://www.google.no/search?q=struct+CvSVMParams

then right click on third hit, end up at the opencv **documentation** http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html

then use your browser's page search functionality (typically [Ctrl F] for "find") to find the text "CvSVMParams" in that page, leading you down the page to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvmparams-cvsvmparams

at this point it's a matter of **reading the documentation**

it is a skill that is essential, so i'm not going to spoil it by repeating here what i found there in 0.5 seconds or so – just take a look. i also recommend trying to do the searching yourself, from scratch. because that's also a fundamental skill that you need and that must be trained up

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I was using 2.3. I was always brought to the old documentation (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ml_support_vector_machines.html?highlight=svm#cvsvmparams) which doesn't state what the default constructor initializes the structure with but I guess it's safe to assume it's the same. In any case I'll try looking through the source code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is constructor:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ddf82d0b154873510802ef75c53e628cd7b2cb13/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp

```
// SVM training parameters
struct SvmParams
{
    int         svmType;
    int         kernelType;
    double      gamma;
    double      coef0;
    double      degree;
    double      C;
    double      nu;
    double      p;
    Mat         classWeights;
    TermCriteria termCrit;

    SvmParams()
    {
        svmType = SVM::C_SVC;
        kernelType = SVM::RBF;
        degree = 0;
        gamma = 1;
        coef0 = 0;
        C = 1;
        nu = 0;
        p = 0;
        termCrit = TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON );
    }

    SvmParams( int _svmType, int _kernelType,
            double _degree, double _gamma, double _coef0,
            double _Con, double _nu, double _p,
            const Mat& _classWeights, TermCriteria _termCrit )
    {
        svmType = _svmType;
        kernelType = _kernelType;
        degree = _degree;
        gamma = _gamma;
        coef0 = _coef0;
        C = _Con;
        nu = _nu;
        p = _p;
        classWeights = _classWeights;
        termCrit = _termCrit;
    }

};
```